# converting advanced c# function into javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, encryption

recently I've been trying to figure out how to convert this function written in c# into node.js, i've been trying for an extremely long time and looking at so many questions to figure out how to do it for around 6 or 7 hours and have had no luck, the code that I am trying to convert into node is an encryption function that uses methods with uint and ulong bits to encrypt an int, I have now come to stackoverflow to ask for help since I've been trying for an extremely long time and haven't found any answers or solutions. I tried my best to explain what the function does, sorry if it's hard to understand. here's the code that I have been trying to convert.
if you do manage to convert it, I would appreciate it if you could explain to me how you did it and how I could do it myself in the future. Thanks

```
private static ulong teaEncrypt(ulong EncryptNum)
{
    uint[] numArray = new uint[4]
    {
        1519839710U,
        2072041700U,
        3432422232U,
        731448588U
    };
    uint num1 = (uint) (EncryptNum & (ulong) uint.MaxValue);
    uint num2 = (uint) (EncryptNum >> 32);
    uint num3 = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < 32; ++index)
    {
        num3 += 3523417902U;
        num1 += (uint) (((int) num2 << 9) + (int) numArray[0] ^ (int) num2 + (int) num3 ^ (int) (num2 >> 5) + (int) numArray[1]);
        num2 += (uint) (((int) num1 << 9) + (int) numArray[2] ^ (int) num1 + (int) num3 ^ (int) (num1 >> 5) + (int) numArray[3]);
    }
    return (ulong) num2 << 32 | (ulong) num1;
}
```

Here is my attempt at converting the code into node.js

```
var uint32 = require('uint32')

var numArray =
[
    1519839710,
    2072041700,
    3432422232,
    731448588
]

function encrypt(EncryptNum)
{
    //const buf = Buffer.allocUnsafe(8);

    var encnum32 = uint32.toUint32(EncryptNum)
    var num1 = uint32.toUint32((encnum32 & 4294967295))
    //console.log(num1)
    var num2 = uint32.toUint32((encnum32 >> 32))
    //console.log(num2)
    var num3 = 0

    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        //console.log("1     " + uint32.toUint32(num2 << 9))
        //console.log("2     " + buf.writeInt32BE(num2, 0))
        num3 += 3523417902;
        num1 += uint32.toUint32(((num2 << 9) + numArray[0] ^ num2 + num3 ^ (num2 >> 5) + numArray[1]))
        num2 += uint32.toUint32(((num1 << 9) + numArray[2] ^ num1 + num3 ^ (num1 >> 5) + numArray[3]))
    }

    return num2 << 32 | num1
}
```

Comment: Usually, we convert step by step while comparing the results. So, in which step there is a difference?

Comment: There are already implementations, too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676514/tea-encryption-in-javascript

Comment: @kelalaka that solution doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: `ulong` is a 64-bit integer type, which doesn’t exist in JavaScript without `BigInt`. Are you targeting browsers or Node.js?

Comment: @Ry- I am targeting node.js.

Comment: Are you able to use Node 10 or 11? If so, use `BigInt`.

Comment: Ok, I will try, thanks for the help, I'm relatively new to node and I'm surprised after all my looking around the internet for solutions I didn't see bigint